# Pre-filling a field of a Symfony form of type EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I'm working on a Symfony project and I'm currently encountering a problem with a form that I want to pre-fill from a collection of objects.

The form field in question is of type EntityType::class. I would like to pre-select elements of this field from a collection that contains objects of the same type(Classe).

One of the solutions I found is to add a 'data' => $defaultClass property in the buildForm, which would contain the data to be inserted, and to pass this object in the parameters($options) on the formBuilder.
Unfortunately, the two objects of type Classe do not appear in the field once the form is generated even though the $options variable contains the objects.

Thanks in advance for your help. Here are the codes concerned :

**SearchCourseData**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Data;

  use App\Entity\Classe;
  use App\Entity\Teacher;
  use App\Entity\Location;

  class SearchCourseData
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 */
public $page = 1;

/**
 * @var Classe[]
 */
public $classe = [];

// Missing lines

/**
 * @var String
 */
public $status;
}
```

**Code SearchCourseForm**

```
class SearchCourseForm extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $defaultClass = new Classe();
    if (!empty($options['data']->classe)) {
        $defaultClass = $options["data"]->classe;
    }

    $builder
            ->add('classe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Classe::class,
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (ClasseRepository $qb) {
                    return $qb->createQueryBuilder('a')->orderBy('a.title', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => function (Classe $atelier) {
                    return($atelier->getTitle());
                },
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Atelier',
                    'class' => 'select-classes'
                ],
                'data' => $defaultClass,
                
            ])
               >add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Disponible' => "Disponible",
                    'Brouillon' => "Brouillon",
                    'Archivé' => "Archivé"
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => SearchCourseData::class,
        'method' => 'GET',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ]);
   
}

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return '';
}

}
```

**Code CourseController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/course")
 */
class CourseController extends AbstractController {

/**
 * @Route("/",name="course")
 */
public function courseList(CourseRepository $courseRepository, Request $request) {


        $data = new SearchCourseData();
        
        $defaultClassB = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class)->find(49);
        $defaultClassA = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class)->find(1);

        $defaultClass[] = new ArrayCollection();
        $defaultClass[0] = $defaultClassA;
        $defaultClass[1] = $defaultClassB;

        $data->classe = $defaultClass;

        
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchCourseForm::class, $data);
       
}
}
```

Comment: 1st of all: From `$defaultClass[] = new ArrayCollection();` to `$defaultClass = new ArrayCollection();` Then use `$defaultClass->add($defaultClassA);`

Comment: Also add `new ArrayCollection();` for your `SearchCourseData` in constructor
`public function __construct(){
$this->classe = new ArrayCollection();
}`
then in controller
`$defaultClassA = $this->getDoctrine()...`
`$data->classe->add($defaultClassA);` and `$data->classe->add($defaultClassB);`

Comment: Thanks for your message, the problem is not related to the filling of the table but rather to the display of the table in buildform. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@V-light is right you are setting a collection in an index of an array - then overwrite it...

```
$defaultClass[] = new ArrayCollection();
// === $defaultClass[0] = new ArrayCollection();
```

the correct and easiest way would be:

```
/**
 * @Route("/course")
 */
class CourseController extends AbstractController {

/**
 * @Route("/",name="course")
 */
public function courseList(CourseRepository $courseRepository, Request $request) {


        $data = new SearchCourseData();            
        $data->classe = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classe::class)->findById([49, 1]);

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchCourseForm::class, $data);
       
}
}
```

EDIT - the corrected form:
'data' of classe gets set by the ModelTransformer automaticly.

```
class SearchCourseForm extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('classe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Classe::class,
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (ClasseRepository $qb) {
                    return $qb->createQueryBuilder('a')->orderBy('a.title', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => function (Classe $atelier) {
                    return($atelier->getTitle());
                },
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Atelier',
                    'class' => 'select-classes'
                ],
                
            ])
               >add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Disponible' => "Disponible",
                    'Brouillon' => "Brouillon",
                    'Archivé' => "Archivé"
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => SearchCourseData::class,
        'method' => 'GET',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ]);
   
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have made the changes however, this does not solve the problem as the $data->class variable contained the classes and the form does receive the expected classes ($defaultClass in SearchCourseForm)

Comment: remove `data` in the form type - this is almost never needed. this is how the form works - its transforms the given data class to the form.

Comment: Even if I remove the data option in the form, the field does not display the classes, can you help me more?

Comment: are the classes present  in the EntityType? If they are not present there is no way to select them.